# jasmine testcase for testing function that calls async call

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

```
    var count  = 0;
    function abc(){
        asyncService.getCount(function(response){
            count = response.data;
        }, function(error){
               console.log(error);
        });
    }

    it('check count', function(){
        asyncService.getCount.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(2));
        ctrl.abc();
        expect(count).toBe(2);
    }
```

I want to test the value of count in jasmine. Please help me with this. I couldn't find any solution for this.
I mocked the service also. But still it is giving count as 0

Answer (score 0):

Use $q and you can resolve it yourself with $rootScope.$digest();.

```
it('check count', function(){
    asyncService.getCount.and.returnValue($q.resolve(2));
    ctrl.abc();
    $rootScope.$digest();
    expect(count).toBe(2);
}
```

$q is the AngularJS wrapper for Promise.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use **spyOn** with the async service.
2. The response variable
   **count** is being set inside a callback function passed to the async service. The return value of that async service seems
   insignificant. So, you have to mock the service with **callFake**
   and execute the callback.

JSFiddle: [Jasmine Async Callback Handling](http://jsfiddle.net/rajeshsathyakumar/nz98dk71/8/)

```
    describe('testing', function(){
    it('testing async service', function(){
        spyOn(asyncService, 'getCount').and.callFake(function(res, err){
            res({data: 2})
        })
      abc();
      expect(count).toBe(2);
    })
  })
```

**Note:** You have to use Jasmine version 2 or more for the above snippet to work.